# separate fields based on first column content, match in second column and subtract in fourth column values in awk

Tags: awk

My input file is like:

```
a10 otu1 xx 44
b24 otu2 xxx 52
x35 otu3 xy 11
x45 otu3 zz 22
z452 Otu5 rr 78
control1 otu1 w 4
control2 otu2 ee 30
control3 otu3 tt 20
control4 otu4 yy 10
```

First, I want to separate control from the others in column 1, and then match second column
values of control with other’s second column. Where match does find in second column, I want
to subtract the corresponding values in fourth column.

Output file would be:

```
a10 otu1 xx 40
b24 otu2 xxx 22
x35 otu3 xy -9
x45 otu4 zz 12
z452 Otu5 rr 78
```

Now, to match the second column and subtract values in fourth column, I use:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$2 in a?a[$2]-$4:$4; next} !b[$2]++ {print $1,$2,$3,a[$2]}' inputfile.txt{,}
```

How can I feed separate field information (control vs others) in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
!/^control/{
  a[++count1]=$NF
  b[count1]=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3
  next
}
{
  c[++count2]=$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count1;i++){
    print b[i],a[i]-c[i]
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

---

---

***More generic solution:*** In case you don't want to hardcode field values in first array a and you have more than 4 fields in first file then try following.

```
awk '
!/^control/{
  a[++count1]=$NF
  $NF=""
  sub(/ +$/,"")
  b[count1]=$0
  next
}
{
  c[++count2]=$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count1;i++){
    print b[i],a[i]-c[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: While this may be an answer to OP's problem, code-only answers are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow. Please consider adding some explanation to the code provided as it will benefit both OP and future visitors.

Comment: @SandraRossi, I usually do add explanation to answers will add in sometime and let you know then.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( /^control/ ) {
        control[$2] = $NF
    }
    next
}
!/^control/ {
    $NF = $NF - control[$2]
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
a10 otu1 xx 40
b24 otu2 xxx 22
x35 otu3 xy -9
x45 otu3 zz 2
z452 Otu5 rr 78
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on this:

```
/^control/ {
  a[$2]=a[$2]-$4
  next
}

{
  a[$2]=a[$2]+$4
  b[$2]=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3
}

END {
  for(i in b) print b[i] OFS a[i]
}
```

This subtracts any values on `control` lines, adds any values on other lines, storing them in the array `a[]`. It maintains an array of line content, `b[]`.

By storing content in the array, it's possible for there to be multiple data or control lines affecting the value, and they can appear in any order in your input (since 44 - 40 is the same as -40 + 44).

Note that because our END for loop steps through the array, output is not guaranteed to be in the same order as input.